# How to join two stored procedure ObjectResults in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using the Entity Framework to function import two stored procedures from my database.

The functions are as follows:

```
_db.GetDeviceTypeModelAttributes(deviceTypeID, deviceModelID);
_db.GetDeviceConfigurableAttributes(deviceID, true);
```

Both functions return a `System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<int?>`.

What's the best way to get them into one result set? Using the `.Union` extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they have the same number and type of columns, with the same names, then the easiest would be the Concat extension, unless you need to make sure the contents are unique in which case use Union.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you create another stored procedure which calls both of the others?